# JADE agent data communication

Tags: java, agent, agents-jade

In my agent program(using jade), I have 5 agents, in which one agent is a coordinator others are device agents. All 4 device agents send a array to coordinator.

I want coordinator to receive all 4 arrays and store them as single array. How can I do it?

I send messages via ACLmessage(strings)

Comment: How are you handling the received messages in the coordinator?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should send your arrays in the 4 messages with `msg.setContentObject((Serializable)yourObject)`
2. At the reception :

   1. do a cast : `yourLocalObject=(yourObjectType) msg.getContentObject();`
   2. Then `globalarray.merge(yourLocalObject)`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using jade.proto.AchieveREInitiator behaviour by the Coordinator. This allows for a simple conversation with multiple responders.

The responders, your 4 device agents will respond with jade.proto.AchieveREResponder behiours.

The code should look alil something like this on the Coordinator side

```
class CoordinatorRequestService extends AchieveREInitiator
{

    String agentName;
            String Service;

    public CoordinatorRequestService (Agent a, ACLMessage msg,String Service ,String agentLocalID) {
        super(a, msg);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.agentName=agentLocalID;
                    this.Service=Service;
    }

    protected Vector prepareRequests(ACLMessage predefinedRequest)
    {


                ACLMessage requestmsg=new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.REQUEST);
                requestmsg.addreciever(//add your agents here)
                requestMsgVector.add(requestmsg);
                return requestMsgVector;
    }

protected void handleInform(ACLMessage inform)
            {
               recieveData=inform.extractDataRecieved();
               globalarray.append(recieveData)

            }
```

Google to find more examples of Contract net and achieve communication.

Goodluck